# about why -1%2=-1?

Tags: xcode

I search in google with -1%2 is (-1) mod 2 = 1, but in xcode -1%2= -1. Have any one tell me why? Thank your help!^.^

http://www.google.com.hk/#hl=zh-TW&source=hp&q=-1%252&oq=-1%252&aq=f&aqi=&aql=1&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=2572l7521l0l7993l10l10l0l9l0l0l154l154l0.1l1l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=1573ccabb4b5821b&biw=929&bih=825

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modulo operator in Objective-C returns the wrong result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430737/modulo-operator-in-objective-c-returns-the-wrong-result)

Answer (score 3):

This text was taken from [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430737/modulo-operator-in-objective-c-returns-the-wrong-result)

Objective-C is a superset of C99 and C99 defines `a % b` to be negative when `a` is negative. See also the [Wikipedia entry on the Modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) and this [StackOverflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907565/c-python-different-behaviour-of-the-modulo-operation)

Something like `(a >= 0) ? (a % b) : ((a % b) + b)` (which hasn't been tested and probably has unnecessary parentheses) should give you the result you want.

Comment: +1 for link to other SO question.  Of interest to those looking into the difference between modulo and remainder: http://codewiki.wikispaces.com/mod+and+rem

Answer (score 2):

Often, the modulo operator is calculated using:

```
number % modulus := number - (number / modulus) * modulus
```

In your case, you get `(-1) - (-1/2)*2 = (-1) - (0) = -1`. Note that the -1/2 evaluates to 0 since we are using integar math.

It is beyond me if all computers operate this way, or if it varies depending on the hardware, but I remember this coming up in a class years ago.