# bilinear interpolation for angles

Tags: python-3.x, bilinear-interpolation

I have a 2d array of directional data. I need to interpolate over a higher resolution grid however the ready made functions like scipy interp2d, etc don't account for the discontinuity between 0 and 360.

I have code for doing this for a single grid of 4 points (thanks [How to perform bilinear interpolation in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8661537/how-to-perform-bilinear-interpolation-in-python) and [Rotation Interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708476/rotation-interpolation)) however I would like it to accept big data sets at once - just like the interp2d function. How can I encorporate this into the code below in a way which doesn't just loop over all of the data?

Thanks!

```
def shortest_angle(beg,end,amount):
    shortest_angle=((((end - beg) % 360) + 540) % 360) - 180
    return shortest_angle*amount    

def bilinear_interpolation_rotation(x, y, points):
    '''Interpolate (x,y) from values associated with four points.

    The four points are a list of four triplets:  (x, y, value).
    The four points can be in any order.  They should form a rectangle.
    '''

    points = sorted(points)               # order points by x, then by y
    (x1, y1, q11), (_x1, y2, q12), (x2, _y1, q21), (_x2, _y2, q22) = points

    if x1 != _x1 or x2 != _x2 or y1 != _y1 or y2 != _y2:
        raise ValueError('points do not form a rectangle')
    if not x1 <= x <= x2 or not y1 <= y <= y2:
        raise ValueError('(x, y) not within the rectangle')
    # interpolate over the x value at each y point
    fxy1 = q11 + shortest_angle(q11,q21,((x-x1)/(x2-x1)))
    fxy2 = q12 + shortest_angle(q12,q22,((x-x1)/(x2-x1)))    
    # interpolate over the y values 
    fxy = fxy1 + shortest_angle(fxy1,fxy2,((y-y1)/(y2-y1)))

    return fxy
```

Comment: What is the shortest angle function suposed to do? `-90 % 360 = 270` I think you are trying to account for special cases by adding 720º and doing some weird things.

Comment: It finds the smallest angle between two angles: e.g. shortest_angle(10,350) = -20 not 340 like a normal linear function would find

Comment: And why are you calculating the shortest angle for a pair of integer values that are not angles?

Comment: they are - it's directional data, say wind direction for example.

Comment: I posted a general answer that does linear and bilinear interpolation. You may need to take into account the semallest angle part, but I would keep that part out of the interpolation if able. If you have any question about how it works ask it in a comment to the answer please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to reuse some personal `Point` and `Point3D` simplified classes for this example:

### `Point`

```
class Point:
    #Constructors
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    # Properties
    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = float(value)

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._y

    @y.setter
    def y(self, value):
        self._y = float(value)

    # Printing magic methods
    def __repr__(self):
        return "({p.x},{p.y})".format(p=self)

    # Comparison magic methods
    def __is_compatible(self, other):
        return hasattr(other, 'x') and hasattr(other, 'y')

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not self.__is_compatible(other):
            return NotImplemented
        return (self.x == other.x) and (self.y == other.y)

    def __ne__(self, other):
        if not self.__is_compatible(other):
            return NotImplemented
        return (self.x != other.x) or (self.y != other.y)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if not self.__is_compatible(other):
            return NotImplemented
        return (self.x, self.y) < (other.x, other.y)

    def __le__(self, other):
        if not self.__is_compatible(other):
            return NotImplemented
        return (self.x, self.y) <= (other.x, other.y)

    def __gt__(self, other):
        if not self.__is_compatible(other):
            return NotImplemented
        return (self.x, self.y) > (other.x, other.y)

    def __ge__(self, other):
        if not self.__is_compatible(other):
            return NotImplemented
        return (self.x, self.y) >= (other.x, other.y)
```

It represents a 2D point. It has a simple constructor, `x` and `y` properties that ensure they always store `float`s, magic methods for string representation as `(x,y)` and comparison to make them sortable (sorts by `x`, then by `y`). My original class has additional features such as addition and substraction (vector behaviour) magic methods both but they are not needed for this example.

### `Point3D`

```
class Point3D(Point):
    # Constructors
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        super().__init__(x, y)
        self.z = z

    @classmethod
    def from2D(cls, p, z):
        return cls(p.x, p.y, z)

    # Properties
    @property
    def z(self):
        return self._z

    @z.setter
    def z(self, value):
        self._z = (value + 180.0) % 360 - 180

    # Printing magic methods
    def __repr__(self):
        return "({p.x},{p.y},{p.z})".format(p=self)

    # Comparison magic methods
    def __is_compatible(self, other):
        return hasattr(other, 'x') and hasattr(other, 'y') and hasattr(other, 'z')

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not self.__is_compatible(other):
            return NotImplemented
        return (self.x == other.x) and (self.y == other.y) and (self.z == other.z)

    def __ne__(self, other):
        if not self.__is_compatible(other):
            return NotImplemented
        return (self.x != other.x) or (self.y != other.y) or (self.z != other.z)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if not self.__is_compatible(other):
            return NotImplemented
        return (self.x, self.y, self.z) < (other.x, other.y, other.z)

    def __le__(self, other):
        if not self.__is_compatible(other):
            return NotImplemented
        return (self.x, self.y, self.z) <= (other.x, other.y, other.z)

    def __gt__(self, other):
        if not self.__is_compatible(other):
            return NotImplemented
        return (self.x, self.y, self.z) > (other.x, other.y, other.z)

    def __ge__(self, other):
        if not self.__is_compatible(other):
            return NotImplemented
        return (self.x, self.y, self.z) >= (other.x, other.y, other.z)
```

Same as `Point` but for 3D points. It also includes an additional constructor classmethod that takes a `Point` and its z value as arguments.

### Linear interpolation

```
def linear_interpolation(x, *points, extrapolate=False):
    # Check there are a minimum of two points
    if len(points) < 2:
        raise ValueError("Not enought points given for interpolation.")
    # Sort the points
    points = sorted(points)
    # Check that x is the valid interpolation interval
    if not extrapolate and (x < points[0].x or x > points[-1].x):
        raise ValueError("{} is not in the interpolation interval.".format(x))
    # Determine which are the two surrounding interpolation points
    if x < points[0].x:
        i = 0
    elif x > points[-1].x:
        i = len(points)-2
    else:
        i = 0
        while points[i+1].x < x:
            i += 1
    p1, p2 = points[i:i+2]
    # Interpolate
    return Point(x, p1.y + (p2.y-p1.y) * (x-p1.x) / (p2.x-p1.x))
```

It takes a first position argument that will determine the x whose y value we want to calculate, and an infinite amount of `Point` instances from where we want to interpolate. A keyword argument (`extrapolate`) allows to turn on extrapolation. A `Point` instance is returned with the requested x and the calculated y values.

### Bilinear interpolation

I offer two alternatives, both of them have a similar signature to the previous interpolation function. A `Point` whose z value we want to calculate, a keyword argument (`extrapolate`) that turns on extrapolation and return a `Point3D` instance with the requested and calculated data. The difference between these two approaches are how the values that will be used to interpolate are provided:

#### Approach 1

The first approach takes a two-levels-deep nested `dict`. The first level keys represent the x values, the second level keys the y values and the second level values the z values.

```
def bilinear_interpolation(p, points, extrapolate=False):
    x_values = sorted(points.keys())
    # Check there are a minimum of two x values
    if len(x_values) < 2:
        raise ValueError("Not enought points given for interpolation.")
    y_values = set()
    for value in points.values():
        y_values.update(value.keys())
    y_values = sorted(y_values)
    # Check there are a minimum of two y values
    if len(y_values) < 2:
        raise ValueError("Not enought points given for interpolation.")
    # Check that p is in the valid interval
    if not extrapolate and (p.x < x_values[0] or p.x > x_values[-1] or p.y < y_values[0] or p.y > y_values[-1]):
        raise ValueError("{} is not in the interpolation interval.".format(p))
    # Determine which are the four surrounding interpolation points
    if p.x < x_values[0]:
        i = 0
    elif p.x > x_values[-1]:
        i = len(x_values) - 2
    else:
        i = 0
        while x_values[i+1] < p.x:
            i += 1
    if p.y < y_values[0]:
        j = 0
    elif p.y > y_values[-1]:
        j = len(y_values) - 2
    else:
        j = 0
        while y_values[j+1] < p.y:
            j += 1
    surroundings = [
                    Point(x_values[i  ], y_values[j  ]),
                    Point(x_values[i  ], y_values[j+1]),
                    Point(x_values[i+1], y_values[j  ]),
                    Point(x_values[i+1], y_values[j+1]),
                   ]
    for i, surrounding in enumerate(surroundings):
        try:
            surroundings[i] = Point3D.from2D(surrounding, points[surrounding.x][surrounding.y])
        except KeyError:
            raise ValueError("{} is missing in the interpolation grid.".format(surrounding))
    p1, p2, p3, p4 = surroundings
    # Interpolate
    p12 = Point3D(p1.x, p.y, linear_interpolation(p.y, Point(p1.y,p1.z), Point(p2.y,p2.z), extrapolate=True).y)
    p34 = Point3D(p3.x, p.y, linear_interpolation(p.y, Point(p3.y,p3.z), Point(p4.y,p4.z), extrapolate=True).y)
    return Point3D(p.x, p12.y, linear_interpolation(p.x, Point(p12.x,p12.z), Point(p34.x,p34.z), extrapolate=True).y)


print(bilinear_interpolation(Point(2,3), {1: {2: 5, 4: 6}, 3: {2: 3, 4: 9}}))
```

#### Approach 2

The second approach takes an infinite number of `Point3D` instances.

```
def bilinear_interpolation(p, *points, extrapolate=False):
    # Check there are a minimum of four points
    if len(points) < 4:
        raise ValueError("Not enought points given for interpolation.")
    # Sort the points into a grid
    x_values = set()
    y_values = set()
    for point in sorted(points):
        x_values.add(point.x)
        y_values.add(point.y)
    x_values = sorted(x_values)
    y_values = sorted(y_values)
    # Check that p is in the valid interval
    if not extrapolate and (p.x < x_values[0] or p.x > x_values[-1] or p.y < y_values[0] or p.y > y_values[-1]):
        raise ValueError("{} is not in the interpolation interval.".format(p))
    # Determine which are the four surrounding interpolation points
    if p.x < x_values[0]:
        i = 0
    elif p.x > x_values[-1]:
        i = len(x_values) - 2
    else:
        i = 0
        while x_values[i+1] < p.x:
            i += 1
    if p.y < y_values[0]:
        j = 0
    elif p.y > y_values[-1]:
        j = len(y_values) - 2
    else:
        j = 0
        while y_values[j+1] < p.y:
            j += 1
    surroundings = [
                    Point(x_values[i  ], y_values[j  ]),
                    Point(x_values[i  ], y_values[j+1]),
                    Point(x_values[i+1], y_values[j  ]),
                    Point(x_values[i+1], y_values[j+1]),
                   ]
    for point in points:
        for i, surrounding in enumerate(surroundings):
            if point.x == surrounding.x and point.y == surrounding.y:
                surroundings[i] = point
    for surrounding in surroundings:
        if not isinstance(surrounding, Point3D):
            raise ValueError("{} is missing in the interpolation grid.".format(surrounding))
    p1, p2, p3, p4 = surroundings
    # Interpolate
    p12 = Point3D(p1.x, p.y, linear_interpolation(p.y, Point(p1.y,p1.z), Point(p2.y,p2.z), extrapolate=True).y)
    p34 = Point3D(p3.x, p.y, linear_interpolation(p.y, Point(p3.y,p3.z), Point(p4.y,p4.z), extrapolate=True).y)
    return Point3D(p.x, p12.y, linear_interpolation(p.x, Point(p12.x,p12.z), Point(p34.x,p34.z), extrapolate=True).y)


print(bilinear_interpolation(Point(2,3), Point3D(3,2,3), Point3D(1,4,6), Point3D(3,4,9), Point3D(1,2,5)))
```

You can see from both approaches that they use the previously defined `linear_interpoaltion` function, and that they always set `extrapolation` to `True` as they already raised an exception if it was `False` and the requested point was outside the provided interval.

Comment: Thanks for your solution: I changed the value the linear interpolation function returns to 'Point(x, np.mod(p1.y + shortest_angle_change(p1.y, p2.y, ((x-p1.x)/(p2.x-p1.x))),360))' where 'def shortest_angle_change(beg,end,amount):
    shortest_angle=((((end - beg) % 360) + 540) % 360) - 180
    return shortest_angle*amount' is the function which calculates the amount of change over the 2 angles. Works well now - cheers :)

Comment: First of all why use `np.mod` instead of `%`?. Second, `((X % 360) + 540) % 360 - 180` has a redundant module operation and adds 540 instead of 180 when not needed, `(X + 180) % 360 - 180` does exactly the same. Third `linear_interpolation(1, Point(0, 160), Point(1, -180))` yields `Point(1, 180)` which is not inside the [-180, 180) interval.

Comment: Forth, I would not use the shortest angle function inside the interpolation function as that function is used three times inside the bilineal interpolation with different coordinates (x, y or z). Instead modify the `Point` or `Point3D` x, y or z setter to handle angles. If you tell me which of them is the angle (x, y or z) I will edit my answer to show you how I would do it.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. z is the angle - would appreciate your edit! cheers. Also, I mod all of my values by 360 first so I don't have any potential issue you raised with the negative/positive situation.

Comment: I already edited my answer. It was a minor edit in the `Point3D` `z` property setter. I swapped `self._z = float(value)` to `self._z = (value + 180.0) % 360 - 180`. You do not need to mod all your values by 360 now, as the Point3D constructor will handle this mod operation itself ensuring that every `Point3D` instance always has the right value here. You could actually force a `Point3D` instance to store a wrong angle but it would need to be intentional as you will need to access the private attribute `_z` directly.