# Understanding the modulo operation for negative integers

Tags: modulo

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17525046/10535754) answer explains the modulo operation for positive numbers perfectly. But how does modulo operation work differently for negative integers? for example **-1 % 60 == 59 in Python** but **-1 % 60 == -1 in C**.

**The C answer makes sense to me** in that the logic is same as that for a modulo operation involving positive integers. But **what's the skinny with the Python answer**?

**What is the general principle behind modulo operation for negative integers**?

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907565/c-and-python-different-behaviour-of-the-modulo-operation?rq=1) answer doesn't explain the general principle.

TIA.

Comment: I checked that earlier. IMO, it doesn't understand the general (mathematical) principle behind it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The modulo operation on negative numbers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883004/the-modulo-operation-on-negative-numbers-in-python)

Comment: The mathematical principle is simply that in Z/60Z, -1 = 59, so the results in C and Python are actually the same.