# Why do I get an incorrect output from a modulus operation with negative number

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried this code on Dart: I get 28.5

```
void main() {
  double modulo = -1.5 % 30.0;
  print(modulo);
}
```

The same code in Javascript returns -1.5

```js
let modulo =  -1.5 % 30;
console.log(modulo);
```

What is the equivalent of the javascript code above in Dart ?

Comment: Judt an idea: what happens of you add parenthesis, including all but the minus sign? My first guess would be that js does -(n%m) while dart does (-n)%m

Comment: It hasn't always been consistent even within the same language. "In C89 (and historical K&R implementations), the meaning of the remainder operator for negative operands was implementation-defined. This behavior was changed in C99, and the change remains in C11."
https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=87152120

Comment: http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52343.html

Comment: in Python and in math `-1.5 % 30 = 28.5`. See [C and Python - different behaviour of the modulo (%) operation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1907565/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for [`num.operator %`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/num/operator_modulo.html) states (emphasis mine):

> Returns the remainder of the Euclidean division. The Euclidean division of two integers `a` and `b` yields two integers `q` and `r` such that `a == b * q + r` and `0 <= r < b.abs()`.
>
> ...
>
> **The sign of the returned value `r` is always positive.**
>
> See `remainder` for the remainder of the truncating division.

Meanwhile, [`num.remainder`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/num/remainder.html) says (again, emphasis mine):

> The result `r` of this operation satisfies: `this == (this ~/ other) * other + r`. As a consequence **the remainder `r` has the same sign as the divider `this`**.

So if you use:

```dart
void main() {
  double modulo = (-1.5).remainder(30.0);
  print(modulo);
}
```

you'll get `-1.5`.

Note that both values are mathematically correct; there are two different answers that correspond to the two different ways that you can compute a negative quotient when performing integer division.  You have a choice between rounding a negative quotient toward zero (also known as truncation) or toward negative infinity (flooring).  `remainder` corresponds to a truncating division, and `%` corresponds to a flooring division.

Answer (score 2):

An [issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/28408#issuecomment-273212205) was raised about this in the dart-lang repo a while ago. Apparently the `%` symbol in dart is an "Euclidean modulo operator rather than remainder."

An equivalent of what you are trying to do can be accomplished with

```dart
(-1.5).remainder(30.0)
```