# Formula for "overflow subtraction"

Tags: math, computer-science

Say I'm incrementing or decrementing an index which I'll use to move through an array.

The array starts at index 0, and ends at index 4. If I'm at index 0 and want to move back 1 index, I should end up at index 4 (wraps around).

This is probably extremely simple, but for some reason I just can't come up with a formula that would give me this result. "wrap around addition" was pretty straight forward: index % 5 + 1, but I just can't figure out subtraction.

Answer (score 1):

The correct formula for addition is `(index + 1) % 5`. Your version gives the wrong result when `index` is 4.

The correct formula for subtraction depends on the behaviour of the `%` operator in the language you're using:

- In Python, `(index - 1) % 5` is correct because `%` guarantees a result between 0 and 4 inclusive even when the left-hand-side is negative.
- In C and Java, `(index + 4) % 5` is correct, because `%` would return a negative remainder when the left-hand-side is negative. Note that this formula would also work in Python.

For more discussion see [this other Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1907565/12299000).

Answer (score 0):

Formula

```
newindex = (index + increment + arraylen) % arraylen
```

works for increments `+1` and `-1` (forward and backward moving).

`arraylen = 5` in your example