# Difference between C++ remainder and NumPy/Python remainder

Tags: python, c++, numpy

In C++, the following code:

```cpp
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << remainder(-177.14024960054252, 360) << std::endl;
}
```

Compiled with x86-64 GCC 12.2 (https://godbolt.org/z/43MzbE1ve)

Outputs:

```
-177.14
```

However in Python:

```py
np.remainder(-177.14024960054252, 360)
# and
-177.14024960054252 % 360
```

Both output:

```
182.85975039945748
```

According to the numpy docs, `np.remainder` is doing the IEEE remainder function. According to the C++ docs, `remainder` is also doing the IEEE remainder function.

Why are these two numbers different?

Comment: Something to do with the neg? How does IEEE define this on negative numbers?

Comment: Did you look for duplicates? I've seen this question many times here.

Comment: @super Yes but all the answers I found were for integer modulus, not float

Comment: @TomMcLean I don't think that's a factor in this case.

Comment: your godbolt link calls `remainderf` not `remainder`

Comment: *"According to the numpy docs"* - Where, exactly?

Answer (score 5):

Because `np.remainder` is not using the IEEE remainder function.

Quote from the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.remainder.html):

> Computes the remainder complementary to the `floor_divide` function. It
> is equivalent to the Python modulus operator`x1 % x2` and has the
> same sign as the divisor `x2`. The MATLAB function equivalent to
> `np.remainder` is mod.

It also has a warning, stating that it is not the same as Python 3.7’s `math.remainder` and C’s remainder.

> This should not be confused with:
>
> Python 3.7’s `math.remainder` and C’s remainder, which computes the IEEE
> remainder, which are the complement to `round(x1 / x2)`.
>
> The MATLAB rem function and or the C % operator which is the
> complement to `int(x1 / x2).`

For difference between Python's `%` and C's `%`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1907565/14193797).