# Does numpy exactly reproduce all C behaviors on usual operations?

Tags: python, c, numpy

I'm designing an algorithm in python and know I'll want to translate it to C later.

However, mathematical operations in Python might not yield the same result as in C, for instance `4294967295 + 1 = 0` in C for unsigned integers, but not with plain Python integers operations. Therefore, I should not use Python integers in my design.

Can I safely and easily use Numpy to reproduce C behavior ? That is, if I perform usual operations (+, -, *, /, %, casting from float to int or the other way around) on arrays with types `np.uint32` or `np.float64` for instance, am I guaranteed (or can I get this guarantee somehow) to get the same result as a C program with `uint32_t` and `float64_t` ?

I'm only interested of what's part of the C "official behavior", anything that is allowed to depend on the compiler or processor in C can also differ with numpy as if it was another compiler/processor. I'm asking in particular since numpy has a Nan that is not always in C.

**EDIT after comments :**

I'm looking more particularly at this set of operations : (+, -, *, /, %, casting from float to int or the other way around).

I've tried to look at numpy documentation to no avail, and have run a few tests myself, for instance :

**TEST 1 : int32 overflow (`(uint32_t) 4294967295 + (uint32_t) 1 == 0` in C)**

It does not seem to work with numpy scalars

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.uint32(4294967295)
>>> type(a)
<class 'numpy.uint32'>
>>> a += 1
>>> a
4294967296
>>> type(a)
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

But it does with numpy arrays :

```
import numpy
a = numpy.array([4294967295], dtype='uint32')
a += 1
print(a)
print(a.dtype)
```

Output:

```
[0]
uint32
```

But this specific case does not give me any insurance that it always works with arrays.

**TEST 2 : negative integer division : **

`-1/2 == 0` in C for int32.

But in "plain" numpy :

```
two = np.int64(2)
mone = np.int64(-1)
print(mone / two)
print(mone // two)
```

Gives :

```
-0.5
-1
```

I'm wondering whether there is some kind of "switch" to numpy, or operands that I could use, so that numpy would give me 0 in the above case for instance

Comment: Pretty broad question. You didn't even list the operations you want to compare. You didn't even attempt to compare them yourself. Please ask specific questions.

Comment: Re "*Can I safely use Numpy to reproduce C behavior ?*", Well, you just said you couldn't use Python integers to reproduce C behaviour, which is clearly false. Python is a full programming language. It can produce any behaviour you want. So how can we possibly answer this question?

Comment: Re "*numpy has a Nan that is not in C*", C has NaN if the machine does. x86/x86_64 uses IEEE floating-point numbers, so it has NaN

Comment: @ikegami 1. I've added specifications for the operations I want, and tests. 2. "Python is a full programming language. It can produce any behaviour you want" : that's right, I'll add "easily" in my question, I'm looking for an answer that does not involve re-coding C typing and operations myself, obviously ;).  3.  " "numpy has a Nan that is not in C", C has NaN if the machine does" : I'm indeed not very familiar with this point, thanks for the explanation

Comment: Modulo on negative numbers in particular is different - modulo in NumPy implements Python's behavior for modulo, but C implements C's behavior. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907565/c-and-python-different-behaviour-of-the-modulo-operation

Comment: Re "*I'll add "easily" in my question*", All C arithmetic operations on integers can very easily be produced by Python. Float arithmetic would depend on what Python provides for floating types. I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: I think you need to start from the beginning https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_numbers.asp

Comment: @gulpr W3 schools is terrible. No one should start there.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the simple answer is **no**

- divisions of negative integers behaves differently :

`-1/2 == 0` in C for int32.

But in "plain" numpy :

```
two = np.int64(2)
mone = np.int64(-1)
print(mone / two)
print(mone // two)
```

- modulo behaves differently (thanks to @Nick ODell's comment) on negative numbers : numpy (and python) always give a nonnegative result ([How does the modulo (%) operator work on negative numbers in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883004/how-does-the-modulo-operator-work-on-negative-numbers-in-python))

And there seems to be no "switch" or alternative operands built in numpy to reproduce the C behavior