# Can I force array numpy to keep its uint32 type?

Tags: python, numpy, uint32

I would like to reproduce C behavior in Python, presumably using numpy, but I'm running into this issue :

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.uint32(4294967295)
>>> type(a)
<class 'numpy.uint32'>
>>> a += 1
>>> a
4294967296
>>> type(a)
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

In C, with uint32, I'd get `4294967295 + 1 = 0`

Can I force my array a to remain a `numpy.uint32` array in order to get `0` at the end of my script ?

Related to this other question of mine: [Does numpy exactly reproduce all C behaviors on usual operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78180950/does-numpy-exactly-reproduce-all-c-behaviors-on-usual-operations)

Comment: A bitwise AND with 0xFFFF_FFFF would give 0.

Comment: In this specific case you can use: `a = (a+1).astype(numpy.uint32)`.

Comment: You can use `a = np.uint32(a + 1)`

Comment: Does adding a `np.uint32(1)` make a difference? Python `1` becomes a `int64` by default.

Comment: @hpaulj - It worked with an overflow warning.

Comment: It seems to me this behavior violates numpy's own documentation. [Array Scalars](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html#array-scalars) _The primary advantage of using array scalars is that they preserve the array type (Python may not have a matching scalar type available, e.g. int16). Therefore, the use of array scalars ensures identical behaviour between arrays and scalars, irrespective of whether the value is inside an array or not._. Note that `arr = numpy.array([numpy.uint32(4294967295)])` then `arr += 1` remains uint32.

Comment: @tdelaney see my follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78186300/differrent-behavior-between-numpy-arrays-and-array-scalars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using an array here, and this matters, because NumPy doesn't necessarily have the same behavior between a scalar and an array of size one.

For example, in-place operations on an array never change the array dtype.

Example:

```
import numpy
a = numpy.array([4294967295], dtype='uint32')
a += 1
print(a)
print(a.dtype)
```

Output:

```
[0]
uint32
```