# Differrent behavior between numpy arrays and array scalars

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-scalar

This is a follow-up on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78180968/can-i-force-array-numpy-to-keep-its-uint32-type) question.

When we use a numpy **array** with a specific type, it preserves its type following numeric operations.
For example adding 1 to a `uint32` array will wrap up the value to 0 if needed (when the array contained the max `uint32` value) and keep the array of type `uint32`:

```
import numpy
a = numpy.array([4294967295], dtype='uint32')
a += 1   # will wrap to 0
print(a)
print(a.dtype)
```

Output:

```
uint32
[0]
uint32
```

This behavior does not hold for an array **scalar** with the same type:

```
import numpy
a = numpy.uint32(4294967295)
print(a.dtype)
a += 1   # will NOT wrap to 0, and change the scalar type
print(a)
print(a.dtype)
```

Output:

```
uint32
4294967296
int64
```

But according to the [array scalars documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html#array-scalars):

> The primary advantage of using array scalars is that they preserve the array type
>
> ...
>
> Therefore, the use of array scalars ensures **identical behaviour between arrays and scalars**, irrespective of whether the value is inside an array or not.

*(emphasys is mine)*

**My question:**
Why do I observe the above different behavior between arrays and scalars despite the explicit documentation that states they should behave identically ?

Comment: It's confusing... have a read here: https://numpy.org/neps/nep-0050-scalar-promotion.html

Comment: It's confusing indeed. Does it mean that the quote I posted from the documentation is simply incorrect ?

Comment: I would say it is

Comment: You are exploring an edge case.  We don't normally make a scalar like this directly.  More likely it's the result of selecting an element from a large array.  And we pick array dtype to save memory while still avoiding wrap around and overflow issues. So it's not surprising that there will be legacy cases witb a mismatch between documentation and code, and between arrays, scalar arrays, and python scalars. Version 2.0 may correct this, but I hate to imagine all the backward compstibility questions we'll get.

Comment: According to the answer below it will probably be corrected in ver 2.0. BTW - I got to this case via the post linked at the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments: yes, this documentation is imprecise at best. I think it is referring to the behavior between scalars of the same type:

```py
import numpy
a = numpy.uint32(4294967295)
print(a.dtype)  # uint32
a += np.uint32(1)   # WILL wrap to 0 with warning
print(a)  # 0
print(a.dtype)  # uint32
```

The behavior of your example, however, will change due to [NEP 50](https://numpy.org/neps/nep-0050-scalar-promotion.html#nep50) in NumPy 2.0. So as frustrating as the old behavior is, there's not much to be done but wait, unless you want to file an issue about backporting a documentation change. As documented in the [Migration Guide](https://numpy.org/devdocs/numpy_2_0_migration_guide.html).

> The largest backwards compatibility change of this is that it means that the precision of scalars is now preserved consistently...
> `np.float32(3) + 3.` now returns a `float32` when it previously returned a `float64`.

I've confirmed that in your example, the type is preserved as expected.

```py
import numpy
a = numpy.uint32(4294967295)
print(a.dtype)  # uint32
a += 1  # will wrap to 0 
print(a)  # 0
print(a.dtype)  # uint32
numpy.__version__  # '2.1.0.dev0+git20240318.6059db1'
```

The second NumPy 2.0 release candidate is out, in case you'd like to try it:
https://mail.python.org/archives/list/numpy-discussion@python.org/thread/EGXPH26NYW3YSOFHKPIW2WUH5IK2DC6J/

Comment: Do you mean that after NEP 50 the result of my example with the scalar will be 0 (like with the array)  - i.e. making the documentation I quoted more accurate generally ?

Comment: Yes, I added that example specifically. I just tested it in the development version of NumPy, but I think you should be able to see that new behavior in the release candidate.