# Mod operator returning wrong output

Tags: c, math, modulo

In mathematics, the remainder of the integer division of `-7/3` is `+2`, since `-7 = (3)(-3) +2`.

But why does the following code:

```
int r = (-7) % 3;
printf("%d",r);
```

prints `-1`? Somehow it is fooled by the fact that the remainder of the integer division `7/3` is 1, but it shouldn't be happening.

Comment: The `%` operator in C does not give the remainder of the Euclidean division.

Comment: Not in mathematics we say "Euclidean division" which is much more specific than just "integer division"

Comment: Also note that most programming languages have an "integer division" operator and a "modulo" operator, and they give the same results on positive numbers, but they tend to differ on negative numbers. It's a matter of convention. Some languages even have two operators, one called "modulo" and the other called "remainder", which give the same result on positive numbers but differ on negative numbers. And for these languages, the name tend to be unhelpful: the "remainder" operator doesn't give the remainder of the Euclidean division!

Comment: Anyway, the original C language had a shaky specification about how to round the result of division of negative numbers. This was not fixed until the C99 version of the language. But if stuck with old C90 compilers, then the rounding direction is implementation-defined.

Comment: the remainder of the integer division of -7/3 is -1 because `-7 = 3*(-2) - 1`. Duplicate: [C and Python - different behaviour of the modulo (%) operation (duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1907565/995714). `%` is the remainder operation, not modulo

Comment: @lessandro, In C, `%` is the [remainder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20638659/2410359), not certainly the [_mod_ nor _modulo_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo) you are thinking of.